# Filter Hibernate Log messages - To take out Constraint Tree

Tags: hibernate, jersey, logback

I am trying to find out a method to take out the Constraint Tree / Constraint Validation Manager from my logfiles.

I am using Jersey Bean Validation and Hibernate.

```
TRACE ConstraintTree 
TRACE ConstraintValidatorManager - Constraint validator org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.
```

Also I am using logback.xml.

Please can you help me to remove them from my logfiles?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the best approach but if you are really deperate to get rid of these lines, you can simply increase your log level to anything above "TRACE". The lines will still be going through your logging code, but they wont appear in your log file.

Note that any other messages logged at the TRACE level will also disappear from your logs.